# Java Split - wrong length

Tags: java, split

Why am I receiving a length of 3 instead of 4? How can I fix this to give the proper length?

```
String s="+9851452;;FERRARI;;";
String split[]=s.split("[;]");
System.out.println(split.length);
```

Comment: Do you want length of 4 or 5?

Comment: How do i get 5 results? And why? thks!

Comment: @Pablo as I mentioned, it's because there are N+1 things between and to the sides of N tokens: `1;2;3;4;5`. The 5th thing is the blank string at the very end. You can probably just ignore it, but if you're really don't like it, you can do an arraycopy that excludes it.

Comment: 5 if you want a trailing empty after the last semicolon. The 2nd, 4th, and 5th elements would be empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're receiving a length of 3 because for [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)),

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

If you specify a negative limit, it'll work fine:

```
    String s="+9851452;;FERRARI;;";
    String split[]=s.split(";", -1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

You'll just need to ignore or remove the 5th item, or remove the trailing `;` - it shows up because there are 5 (potentially blank) strings on either sides of 4 tokens. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

`String split[]=s.split("[;]", -1);`

Comment: This is a correct answer, but it would be great if you add an explanation. Anyway, +1

Answer (score 0):

The answer for WHY it's not working is in the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29 . "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.".

Answer (score -1):

You can use StringUtils from apache commons lang.

```
String s="+9851452;;FERRARI;;";
Arrays.toString(StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(s, ";"))
```

Comment: It's not an answer to the question.